# JS Form formatting clashing with math functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an html order submit form which has mathmatical functions to add up the values of each item selected and display the total.

However when I attempt to integrate form formatting such as JQtransform or Niceform the JS maths functions stop working...

I am guessing that it is because these formatting methods actually hides the original checkbox/radio btn etc and replaces with the respective image... any ideas how I can sort  this?

here's the examples...

This is the the form without the JS formatting, you can see the functions are working.. - http://psdtohtmluk.co.uk/host/niceforms/niceforms_without.html -

This is the same form with the formatting, here the only working maths function is the 'pages' - http://psdtohtmluk.co.uk/host/niceforms/niceforms_with.html -

Cheers!

Comment: The real checkbox is still there, so it should work fine. It would help if you could post your code. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ Maybe your `onClick()` handler is being overwritten or ignored.

Answer (score 0):

here's the examples...

This is the the form without the JS formatting, you can see the functions are working..
 - http://psdtohtmluk.co.uk/host/niceforms/niceforms_without.html -

This is the same form with the formatting, here the only working maths function is the 'pages'
 - http://psdtohtmluk.co.uk/host/niceforms/niceforms_with.html -

Cheers!